# Unable to get correct FileField.url from django ModelForm instance when saving without committing

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model, and a model form by which to save instances:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="the_image_directory")
    css_file = models.FileField(upload_to="the_image_directory")


class CatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(
        label=_("Cat image"),
        widget=forms.FileInput()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        exclude = ('css_file',)
```

The css file template contains styling for the cat image: `background-image: url("{{ cat.image.url }}")`, which is obviously replaced with the image url when run through the context processor. In pseudocode (for brevity):

```
cat = form.save(commit=False)
cat.css_file = render_to_file("base.css", {"cat": cat})
cat.save()
```

My problem is that I need to get a `Cat` instance's `image` in order to create its `css_file`, but the `cat.image.url` parameter is incorrect when I call `form.save(commit=False)`. Instead of `cat.image.url` being `/media/the_image_directory/some_cat.jpg`, it is `/media/some_cat.jpg`. The `upload_to` seems not to be recognised until I actually call `.save(commit=True)`.

( Edit: it's also incorrect if the filename is duplicated and django needs to append a random suffix, eg `cat_u7uF0aj.jpg` )

Is there a way around this, or do I have to commit twice to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Django moves the file when writing it into the database. You might want to use a post_save signal to write the css file.